# How does "Thou shalt not muzzle the ox that treadeth out the corn." work?

Tags: fallen-london

I have a storylet that is just called '"Thou shalt not muzzle the ox that treadeth out the corn."' It's description only says:

> "...And, the labourer is worthy of his reward." Of course, you may not consider yourself a 'labourer'. Or a 'him'. But everyone likes rewards. [Your Profession will bring you a reward every week. Complete your duties and receive it.]

Apparently it's from using 'An Earnest of Payment' or something, but I don't remember how I got that. I've also read that it gives you an item depending on your profession. The description also mentions something about it being weekly.

How did I get it? Is it renewable? Should I wait until I get a better profession to use it? What does it mean by the portion in brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Thou shalt not muzzle the ox that treadeth out the corn.", is a profession related storylet that becomes available as part of you receiving An Earnest of Payment.

Every week, you will receive An Earnest of Payment, which you can then turn in for the reward specific to your profession. You also receive Professional Perks, which give generic rewards available for any profession.

You should probably use your Earnest of Payment as soon as you get it, as its rewards can really help push you forward in your Qualities. <strike>And while I haven't checked myself, I think that you could safely let your Earnests of Payment stack up,</strike> It seems like you can only have one Earnest of Payment at a time and they can't stack, though there wouldn't be a point anyway, as An Earnest of Payment has no use outside of the "Thou shalt not muzzle the ox that treadeth out the corn." Storylet.

Source: http://echobazaar.wikidot.com/profession

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't let it stack - I think "an earnest of payment" has a max of one, so if you wait until the next week you won't get two chances.

Comment: I can confirm that - I've been letting Professional Perks stack up to reduce Nightmares, and the Earnest of Payment maxes at 1.